# Pandas: how to match multiple pattern (OR) with np.where

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if it is possible with np.where in pandas
to match multiple patterns with a kind of 'OR' argument

For exemple i try to create a new column in my DataFrame called 'kind'
and for each rows to fill it with "test" if the value in another column called 'label'
match any of the listed patterns otherwise to fill with "control".

I'm using this:

```
df['kind'] = np.where(df['label'] == 'B85_C', 'test', 'control')
```

And it is working well with 1 pattern

What i'm looking after is something like this:

```
df['kind'] = np.where(df['label'] == 'B85_C'OR'B85_N' ,'test', 'control')
```

Any ideas how to perform that or if there is alternatives?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the bitwise or:

```
(df['label'] == 'B85_C') | (df['label'] == 'B85_N')
```

or you can use the [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```
df['label'].isin(['B85_C', 'B85_N'])
```

Comment: You mean bitwise `or` ;o)